# Obtaining a monthly max value in PySpark RDD without SQL functions

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, max, rdd

I want to find the monthly max value of this query, to get the busiest airport per month.

Without using SQL commands, is there a pyspark function to obtain the max values and reduce the RDD to only 12 rows (one row per month)?

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from operator import add

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

rows = sc.textFile("data.csv")
data = rows.map(lambda line: line.split(","))
header = data.first()

q = data.filter(lambda line:( line != header))\
    .map(lambda x: (x[1]+'-'+x[16], 1))\
    .reduceByKey(add)\
    .map(lambda x: (x[0].split('-'), x[1]))\
    .map(lambda x: (x[0][0], x[0][1], x[1]))\
    .collect()

sqlContext.createDataFrame(q, ['Month', 'Airport', 'Flights']).show(n=15)

+-----+-------+-------+
|Month|Airport|Flights|
+-----+-------+-------+
|    9|    DAL|   4388|
|    7|    STX|     43|
|    4|    PNS|    834|
|   12|    EUG|    549|
|    5|    ERI|    120|
|    9|    ATL|  34258|
|    7|    PHX|  17846|
|   12|    MYR|    434|
|   11|    CWA|    140|
|    9|    DAY|   1307|
|   12|    ADQ|     60|
|    1|    MTJ|    307|
|   10|    APF|      1|
|    2|    MAF|    657|
|    1|    SRQ|    687|
+-----+-------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try grouping items by key (month), to get a key-value pair rdd, and then get maximum, something like that:

```
max_by_month = (data
  .map(lambda x: (x[0], x))  # Convert to PairwiseRD by month
  # Take a maximum of the passed arguments by the last element (flights)
  .reduceByKey(lambda x1, x2: max(x1, x2, key=lambda x: x[-1])) 
  .values()) # Drop keys
```

Comment: This was a simple and elegant solution, thank you. 
Note: To make it run with the previous code you first have to delete: ".collect()"